# How to create a ListView with custom Widgets depending on object model content

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I would like to create a ListView that has dynamic content.

For example I have a Object/Model of a Pet. It has the properties: name, age, dateOfBirth, dateOfDeath and picture.

Now I want to have logic in each Pet instance custom widget that checks if there is a dateOfDeath or image. If there isn't or its null I don't want to create another Text/Image widget on the screen.

I want it to be something similar to how java has RecylcerView and we craate a custom adapter that can hide components if they are null values.

I have searched and watched many YouTube vidoes and have found nothing that solves my problem. They all just have static data that does not have potential null data.

Here is a example of code that I currently have:

```
class PetListItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final Pet pet;

  PetListItem (this.pet);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            pet.name
          ),
          Text(
            pet.age
          ),
          Text(
            pet.dob
          ),
          Text(
            pet.dod // I want this to display if pet.dod is not null
          ),
          NetworkImage(
              pet.imageURL // I want this to display if pet.imageURL is not null
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally create widget using the ternary operator:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(pet.name),
        Text(pet.age),
        Text(pet.dob),
        pet.dod != null ? Text(pet.dod) : Container(),
        pet.imageURL != null ? NetworkImage(pet.imageURL) : Container(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

If you don't like to return an empty Container in case of null values, you can use the [conditional_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/conditional_builder) package.

```
ConditionalBuilder(
   condition: pet.dod != null,
   builder: (context) => Text(pet.dod),
),

ConditionalBuilder(
   condition: pet.imageURL != null,
   builder: (context) => NetworkImage(pet.imageURL),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use **collection if**

Like this

```
class PetListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Pet pet;

  PetListItem(this.pet);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(pet.name),
          Text(pet.age),
          Text(pet.dob),
          if (pet.dod != null) Text(pet.dod),
          if(pet.imageURL != null) Image.network(pet.imageURL)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know we can use `if` statement inside build.. I'm sure it wasn't possible in previous releases. I know that inline statement was allowed. I just tried that and it works even with `else` or `else if`

Comment: They added it in Dart 2.3. Check it out here https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists

Comment: hmm... that will definitely shorten up my code a bit by removing some methods and replacing them with this one